# Split a string of multiple sentences into single sentences and surround them with html tags

Tags: java, string, substring

I am a Java beginner and currently looking for a method to Split a String `message` into substrings, based on delimiter ( . ). Ideally I have single sentences then and I want to wrap each sentence in HTML tags, i. e. `<p></p>`.

I tried the following with `BreakIterator` class:

```
    BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
    iterator.setText(message);
    int start = iterator.first();
    String newMessage= "";
    for (int end = iterator.next();
         end != BreakIterator.DONE;
         start = end, end = iterator.next()) {
         newMessage= "<p>"+ message.substring(start,end) + "</p>";
         sentences.add(newMessage);
    }
```

This gives back one sentence. I am stuck here, I also want to wrap each number in a each sentence.

The String I have contains something like:

```
    String message = "Hello, John. My phone number is: 02365897458. 
                      Please call me tomorrow morning, at 8 am."
```

The output should be:

```
String newMessage = "<p>Hello, John.</p><p>My phone number is: 
                     <number>02365897458</number>.
                    </p><p>Please call me tomorrow morning, at 8 am.</p>"
```

Is there a possibility to achieve this?

Comment: You just said that you want to surround sentences using `<p>` tags, but your example also adds a `number` tag. Could you please clarify what exactly you are attempting, as in in which situation should which tag be inserted?

Comment: Hi, I want to surround each sentence with a <p> tag and additionally each number in these sentences should be surrounded by <number> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surrounding sentences could be archived by adding a `<p>` at the start, a `</p>` at the end and replacing each full-stop with `.</p><p>`. Take a look at the [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method for strings.

And to add the number tag, you could use a regex replace. The [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method and a regex like `[0-9]+`, depending on what your numbers look like, can do that.

Something similar to this should work (untested):

```
newMessage = "<p>" + message.replace(".", ".</p><p>")
                            .replaceAll("([0-9]+)", "<number>$1</number>") + 
             "</p>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `split` method on Java String.  You can split on `.` and it will return an array of Strings.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using the `StringTokenizer` class, along with the `StringBuilder` class:

```
String message = SOME_STRING;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(message, ".");
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    builder.append("<p>");
    builder.append(tokenizer.nextToken());
    builder.append("</p>");
}
return builder.toString();
```

You can add more delimiters as required for various tags.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you can use the split method. Because you're splitting on dots be sure to escape this in your regex. A simple example (there are other ways to keep the delimiter but I've done it like this for simplicity as you're beginning);

```
    String toSplit = "Hello, John. My phone number is: 02365897458. Please call me tomorrow morning, at 8 am.";
    String[] tokens = toSplit.split("\\.");
    for(String token : tokens) {
        token = "<p>" + token + ".</p>";
    }
```